# installing wordpress on IIS using web platform installer

Tags: php, wordpress, iis-7

I have installed wordpress on my IIS server using web plaform intaller, everything is working fine when i am working on localhost.

when when i am trying to browse from external or another pc, the links are stayed http://localhost/page.php, which should be http://myserver/page.php

even the styling is not applied because of that.

how do I change the Path and make it work??
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have saved in the database that your site url was http://localhost. To access it from everywhere, I'd use your IP address instead, that way you should be able to see it on your local and external machines.

Do a quick export of your db, open in a text editor.

Find/ replace 'localhost' and change it to whatever your computer's IP is.

Import your changed sql file. Should be all good :)